# Python dict datatype error while after reading message from AWS SQS and Put it into AWS DynamoDB

Tags: python-3.x, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, boto3, amazon-sqs

My use case is to take a JSON message from SQS body and insert data into DynamoDB
Using the lambda function in python.
the issue is I am able to read and print the JSON message from SQS queue into cloud watch log but when I try to insert the same JSON in dynamoDB it gives below Error

***Invalid type for parameter Item, value: {'name': 2}, type: class 'str', valid types: class 'dict'***

Below is the lambda code I am using and an error occurred at line number 12 where I am trying to insert using put_item

```
import json
import boto3

dynamodb = boto3.resource('dynamodb')
dynamoTable = dynamodb.Table('message')

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    for record in event['Records']:
        data1 = record["body"]
        jsondata1 = json.loads(data1)
        print(jsondata1)
        dynamoTable.put_item(Item=jsondata1)
```

However, it is able to print the SQS JSON to cloud watch log as below
[image]

Comment: You will get this error when `jsondata1` from your example will be of a string type. Is this the actual code that is giving you the error?

Comment: I am able to print jsondata1 in the console but it's giving an error while  inserting into dynamoDB i.e last line of code dynamoTable.put_item(Item=jsondata1)

Comment: I was trying to recreate the error and accordingly to the error message you are getting, you will get that error only when `jsondata1` is of type string. Where in your code snippet it isn't. Hence my question is if the sample code you provided is the actual code that is giving you an error.

Comment: what happens is dynamoDB expects data in type dictionary but when I print type of jsondata1 its giving string hence actually it should be dict, in conclusion the thing is AWS lambda is not able to convert SQS message to dict data type

Comment: it will be great if u can help me with any other way in python lambda or boto 3 to convert string to dict class

Comment: to your question, it is the only code which is giving the error another thing is when I parse the static value of json it works fine

Comment: How come your `jsondata1 = json.loads(data1)` doesn't error out? `json.loads` accepts string argument and in your example `data1` is not string but dict. In your code if you get rid of `jsondata1 = json.loads(data1)` line and change the last one to `dynamoTable.put_item(Item=data1) ` it should work just fine.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195337/discussion-between-tommy-and-narendra-maru).

Comment: I did try that as well but in both the cases it is giving the same error. i find that the issue is in both values data1 as well as in jsondata1 the type of the value is string class only actually it is not able to convert string in to dict

Answer (score 0):

after so many R&D i am able to find the solution is by splitting the string by comma and then recreating an json which will create json of dict data type and not string

Below is the code for the same solution

```
import json
import boto3
import ast

dynamodb = boto3.resource('dynamodb')
dynamoTable = dynamodb.Table('message')

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    for record in event['Records']:
        data1 = record["body"]
        jsondata1 = json.loads(data1)
        mess1 = jsondata1["Message"]
        id = jsondata1["MessageId"]
        jsonmess = json.loads(mess1)
        s = jsonmess.replace("{" ,"")
        finalstring = s.replace("}" , "")
        split = finalstring.split(",")
        dict = {'messageID':id}
        for x in split:
            keyvalue = x.split(":")
            print(keyvalue)
            dict[keyvalue[0]]=keyvalue[1]
        dynamoTable.put_item(Item=dict)
```